Expo SDK 51 and graphql-request not working
I am using graphql-request to get my data from Hygraph in expo SDK 51 react native app.
I get the error:
Unable to resolve "graphql-request" from "constants\GlobalApi.ts"

I looked through and nothing works. I have install graphql-request using
npm add graphql-request graphql

Anyone with help?

Any update on this? Running into the same issue

in package.json
{
  "graphql": "^16.8.1",
  "graphql-request": "^6.0.0"
}


I have that in package.json but it still gives the same error

import { gql, request } from 'graphql-request/build/entrypoints/main';
this working for me

Did you see this "Module '"c:/Users/*******/node_modules/graphql-request/package"' has no exported member 'request'." in the vscode problems tab?

fint the build and entrypoints and main like this import { gql, request } from 'graphql-request/build/entrypoints/main';

import { gql, request } from 'graphql-request/build/entrypoints/main';

This option doesn't work in larger scale projects and won't be auto-imported properly. The downgrade option is better than trying to set this up properly.

You can change your graphql and graphql-request in package.json file to:
{
   "graphql": "^15.8.0",
   "graphql-request": "^6.1.0"
}


This worked for me. Thanks.
